# NodeJs Design Pattern - Big variables to be declared in Global Config or inside API Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Working on a nodeJs Application.I have an API Route which has high hitting rate. And in the controller function for the API I have to use a relatively Big Array. I wasn't sure if i should declare this in config.js Which i am supposing only loaded once in the memory or shall i declare it in the function itself where it'll be loaded in memory for every new incoming request. I am not sure which method is memory efficient.

Method 1.

```
/* Config.js */
const bigArray = ["String1", "String2",...];
module.exports = {bigArray};


/* Route.js*/
const {bigArray} = require("config.js");

router.get("/my_api", (req,res,next)=>{

    for(let item of bigArray){
        console.log(item);
    }
    return res.json({status: 1});
})
```

Method 2.

```
/* Route.js*/


router.get("/my_api", (req,res,next)=>{

    const bigArray = ["String1", "String2",...];
    for(let item of bigArray){
        console.log(item);
    }
    return res.json({status: 1});
})
```

Can somebody point me to right direction or where to look on it for mode details..

Comment: if you can use a generator to create the bigArrayList?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *memory efficient*?

Comment: Definetly **NOT** in the callback function. I repeat **NOT** in the callback function. Except of course if you're planning on requesting `"/my_api"` only once.

Comment: @MattWay Memory efficient means the way in which i can reduce hogging of Ram. From my understanding if i write in the handler function then for every request i am creating an array of lets say size 1KB then for 1000 requests 1MB is blocked. But if i use method 1, will be remain loaded in the memory previous to the route handler which is only1KB now for any number of requests i am supposing it wont be loaded in memory again and again...

Comment: @DagaArihant Not exactly, as those 1000 requests won't happen at the same time*. One handler would run after the other, each allocating and deallocating the large array. It would take the same 1KB, but be much slower. *( *: assuming you are not doing something asynchronous )*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the array is not mutated, yes you probably shouldn't create it inside the route handler that is executed multiple times. But no, there's no reason to put it in a separate `config.js` file. Just write

```
// Route.js
const bigArray = ["String1", "String2",...];
router.get("/my_api", (req, res, next) => {
    for (let item of bigArray) {
        console.log(item);
    }
    return res.json({status: 1});
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is what i was looking for.